# How to get im4java working with BufferedImage

Tags: java, imagemagick, jmagick, im4java

I am using [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/) version 1.4.0 to access [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) functionality from Java. It is working well for processing images to and from files.

The [Developers Guide](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/docs/dev-guide.html) has a section on using Buffered Images instead of writing output to a file, and there is a test (TestCase13) that demonstrate using Buffered Images as output. However, when I run any action with a Buffered Image I receive an `org.im4java.core.CommandException` stating: `no ImageReader for given format`.

I have tried a number of different things (including adding the `jai_imageio.jar` to provide additional formats), but nothing seems to work. A basic test-code that shows the problem, (based on im4java.jar's TestCase13) is:

```
@Test
public void shouldWorkWithBufferedImageTest() throws InterruptedException, IOException, IM4JavaException {
    ProcessStarter.setGlobalSearchPath("C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q8");
    String iImageDir =  "C:\\images";

    String var1 = "png";
    IMOperation imOp = new IMOperation();
    imOp.addImage(new String[]{iImageDir + "sample-image=6.png"});
    imOp.blur(Double.valueOf(2.0D)).paint(Double.valueOf(10.0D));
    imOp.addImage(new String[]{var1 + ":-"});
    ConvertCmd convertCmd = new ConvertCmd();
    Stream2BufferedImage stream2BufferedImage = new Stream2BufferedImage();
    convertCmd.setOutputConsumer(stream2BufferedImage);
    convertCmd.run(imOp, new Object[0]);
    BufferedImage outImage = stream2BufferedImage.getImage();
    ImageIO.write(outImage, "PNG", new File(iImageDir + "tmpfile.png"));
    DisplayCmd.show(iImageDir + "tmpfile.png");
}
```

Running this throws the following error:

```
    org.im4java.core.CommandException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: no ImageReader for given format
    at org.im4java.core.ImageCommand.run(ImageCommand.java:219)
    at test.groovy.services.ImageManipulation.JavaBufferedImageManipulationTest.shouldWorkBufferedImageTest(JavaBufferedImageManipulationTest.java:31)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: no ImageReader for given format
    at org.im4java.core.Stream2BufferedImage.consumeOutput(Stream2BufferedImage.java:82)
    at org.im4java.process.ProcessStarter.processOutput(ProcessStarter.java:276)
    at org.im4java.process.ProcessStarter.access$200(ProcessStarter.java:54)
    at org.im4java.process.ProcessStarter$2.call(ProcessStarter.java:433)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The error occurs on the the `convertCmd.run` line, however, the problem seems to be with setting the outputConsumer as the stream2BufferedImage. How do I fix this? Is there a known bug with im4java and BufferedImages? Is there a better work-around than exporting to a temp-file and then reading it back in to a BufferedImage? I am aware of JMagick (as an alternative to im4java) but have not found this a good solution for other reasons.

Thanks, in advance, for any assistance or ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see in this example i have the input source as buffered Image and output is also as buffered image . I hope this can help you.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {   
        IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
        op.addImage();                       
        op.resize(350)
        op.addImage("png:-")               
        BufferedImage images = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg")); 

        // set up command
        ConvertCmd convert = new ConvertCmd();
        Stream2BufferedImage s2b = new Stream2BufferedImage();
        convert.setOutputConsumer(s2b);

        // run command and extract BufferedImage from OutputConsumer
        convert.run(op,images);
        BufferedImage img = s2b.getImage();
    }
```